# JavaFX MediaPlayer creating hundreds of threads with mp4s

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

When using the following code

```
Media media = new Media("video.mp4");
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
MediaView mv = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
mediaPlayer.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
```

the video plays great. However, when debugging some other areas of the code, I noticed that the mediaplayer seems to be creating threads like crazy. The debugger shows

> Daemon Thread [Thread-X](Running)

where X is continually growing. It appears the threads are being destroyed, but the count is up to over a 1000 threads created in under a minute.

If I use the same setup, but replace the mp4 with just an mp3, this doesn't happen.

Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not a bug but is the default **design** of the `JavaFX MediaPlayer`. Sad, but we need to wait till the dev team decides to replace the current `GLib` used for rendering the video.

*Kirill Kirichenko* says on an similar issue raised as a [JIRA](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-26083) and I quote :

> You can observe many threads because we attach/detach native threads
>   from native layer on each frame. This is by design now.

The reason for this was given by him on a different [JIRA](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-24622) and again I quote:

> This happens due to calls AttachCurrentThread on the current JVM every
>   time there is a frame. I can be fixed in the future when we switch to
>   the newer GLib. Currently this is the safest way to render and not to
>   crash jvm.